# Sharing MP3 I bought from Amazon

Tags: music

I think it's rude to just download MP3s from the Internet so I buy them from Amazon. But I want to share them with my immediate family. I know that if it was a CD, I could just lend it to them, but lending MP3 doesn't really work (I can't be bothered deleting files every time and copying them back again). Is that allowed to duplicate the files to my brother's smartphone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Reproduction is an exclusive right of the copyright owner. (17 USC §106, Section 3 of the Copyright Act of Canada, Section 16 of the Copyright, Designs and Patents Act 1988 of the UK, etc.)

Comment: Probably smart to slow down a bit. It's entirely possible that Amazon's digital rights extend to devices other than those owned by the account holder. I know that Apple works this way, anyone who can sync with the iTunes can get the music. These cases are about DRM. If you copy an Amazon song onto a phone and it actually plays, it's likely that you are not violating the license. In other words, try putting the song on the phone; see what happens.

Comment: The suggestion to reproduce *before* checking whether you have a licence to reproduce is not prudent advice.

Comment: Generally speaking, it's not. But this is Amazon. They have one of the most, if not the most, sophisticated DRM solutions available. I absolutely think it's perfectly defensible to assume that if it plays on a device it's because Amazon enabled it to play on the device.

Comment: [Amazon Music](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Music): in January 2008 it became the first music store to sell music without digital rights management (DRM) from the four major music labels. [Amazon self describes as](http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=201377410): "*one of the world's largest DRM-free (digital rights management free) digital music stores.*"

Comment: Regardless, let's say you get an mp3 from Amazon without a license to reproduce it. Are you saying that if you reproduce it and it happens to play on some other device, that this means you had license to reproduce it after all?

Comment: well that blows my theory away

Comment: I wouldn't call that reproduction. A person can have the file on more than one device. OP implies a misunderstanding ("deleting and copying back") that only one copy of the file can exist. But I've already shown how much I don't know. I obviously haven't read amazons t&c in a long time! Let's just say I wouldn't be surprised if the license allows me to play the song on my brother's phone. Said differently, the license could extend to family members.

Comment: @jqning It *is* reproduction. It is called format/device shifting. In Canada, format shifting is explicitly allowed in the copyright act. In the US, format shifting is fair use when done for personal use. Neither Canada's statute nor the fair use finding in the US allows for format/device shifting in order to share the work with a family member. And sure, the licence *could* extend to family members. You can do whatever the licence says you can do. But if an act wasn't reproduction, you wouldn't even need a licence or a finding of fair use, or a statutory exception.

Comment: so u have a citation for that fair use opinion? The Amazon license is for "personal non-commercial purposes" - if you are telling me that the contours of that license have been defined in a court, I'll only admit surprise. In the meantime, I'd argue that I can put a song on my pc, my portable device, my media center at home. Etc. I can put in on my phone and play it for my friends at a party. Why can't I put it on my bro's phone to play at a party? That's still personal use. Can I put my song on my MP3 player and give it to a friend to take to the hospital to play for my sick friend?

Comment: I'm sure this needs to move to chat. I'm walking down the street so can't do it myself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37619/discussion-between-dawn-and-jqning).

Comment: @Dawn: If you could make a copy without circumventing anything that should have prevented it, that just means you are not violating the DMCA act in the USA, or perhaps similar laws in other countries. It can still be copyright infringement.

Comment: @gnasher I'm not sure I understand your comment. How would you like me to update my answer?

Comment: I'm confused to, should I mark it as not the correct answer? it's irresponsible to let people that know nothing about law to accept answers.

Comment: This answer is correct.

Answer (score -1):

Check the exact license terms. I haven't checked Amazon's terms; if I download music from Apple's iTunes store, there is a license that allows me to store this music and play it from several Apple devices - I assume that Apple has negotiated a contract with the record companies so they can offer that license. Amazon may have a similar license. And of course copyright law may or may not give you certain permissions.